# C: "invalid use of undefined type ‘struct X’ & dereferencing pointer to incomplete type" errors

Tags: c, compiler-errors, multidimensional-array

I've been perusing similar questions to mine for a couple of days but still haven't found a solution. Thanks any any help:

I have two files, one containing methods for dealing with rational numbers and one that handles them in a 2 dimensional array. My problem is matrix.c doesn't recognize the fraction structure in contained in fraction.c. I believe my problem is somehow related to the way I declared my 2d array.

In fraction.c:

```
struct fraction {
   int integer;
   int num;
   int den;
};
typedef struct fraction* fractionRef;  //This line is in fraction.h
```

In matrix.c:

```
#include "fraction.h"

typedef struct matrix* matrixRef;

struct matrix {
   int rows;
   int columns;
   fractionRef *m;
}matrix;

matrixRef new_matrix ( int rows, int columns ) {
   matrixRef matrix;
   matrix = (matrixRef)malloc( sizeof( matrix ) );
   matrix->m = (fractionRef*)calloc( rows, sizeof( fractionRef ) );
   int i;
   for ( i=0; i<=rows; i++ )
     matrix->m[i] = (fractionRef)calloc( columns, sizeof( fractionRef ) );
   assert( matrix->m );
   return matrix;

}
void free_matrix ( matrixRef freeMe ) {
   if ( freeMe != NULL ){
      int i, j;
      for( i = 0; i <= freeMe->rows; i++ ){
         for ( j = 0; j <= freeMe->columns; j++ ){
            free_fraction( freeMe->m[i][j] ); //ERROR OCCURS HERE
         }
      }
      freeMe->rows = 0;
      freeMe->columns = 0;
      free(freeMe);
      freeMe = NULL;
   }
}
```

The error I get corresponds to the line in matrix.c I marked.

```
matrix.c:47: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct fraction’
matrix.c:47: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

This is probably all because I learned java BEFORE c, big mistake!!! Thanks again for any help.

EDIT: Thanks everyone. So the way I see it now is everything in the header .h files are similar to public in java. My fraction struct definition wasn't "public" to the c compiler so my matrix.c wasn't able to access it.

Comment: One thing you'll have to adjust to with C: words such as ```public``` and ```private``` don't apply perfectly, and the word ```static``` means something different than it does in Java.  "There are ways" when you get more advanced in C to create ```structs``` which have something akin to private members.  But with regard to ```static```: in C, at the file scope level, this means "private" -- declaring a variable which cannot be accessed from another .c file no matter what you put in header files.  ```static``` has additional effects at file scope and different effects at function scope.

Comment: Do you allocate any memory that is ```sizeof(fraction)``` and assign those to each element ```matrix->m[i][j] = calloc(1, sizeof(fraction))``` somewhere?  You can't merely allocate pointers (what you call ```fractionRef```) to the ```struct```, you must at some point allocate the actual ```struct fraction```s, just like you did for the matrix.  You might just have not included that code, which is fine.  Just wondering, since you marked that line as causing some error, I wonder.  Also, I would expect that ```free_fraction()``` must have the parameter of type ```struct fraction *```.

Comment: Ok, I see there is more to note here than I first thought.  I have to ask before going on: are you trying to create *rows* number of row pointers, and then have each row contain *columns* number of fraction pointers?  Or do you want each row to contain *columns* number of actual fraction structs?  If the first case, you have to allocate each struct fraction individually.  If the second, you have to allocate each row of fractions all at once.  Let me know, then I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 12):

You must move the definition of the `struct` into the `fraction.h` file.  Unlike Java, the compiler and linker do not "magically" cause one `.c` file to reference information inside another `.c` file.  (It could be done if you `#include` one .c file in another -- a bad idea.)

The directive

#include "fraction.h"

causes the text contents of the header file to be placed, as if by cut-and-paste, at the line with that directive.  The compiler processes one input file at a time, reading in the `#include`'d files, and all the needed information must be present while that one `.c` file is compiled.

To help with your understanding, I will point out a terrible way to accomplish what you require:  simply cut-and-paste the struct definition of `struct fraction` into the top of `matrix.c`, immediately prior to `#include "fraction.h"` -- the result will compile.  In Java, the compiler might complain that you have declared some duplicate types.  In C, what you've done is define two different structs, which happen to have an identical memory layout and the same name.  Only the same memory layout is needed to make them interchangable from the perspective of linking together object files.

Yes, this is a misunderstanding you picked up from Java.  It's wonderful that you are learning C!

Comment: +1 for making the bridge between Java and C easier to cross for the OP (I don;t know Java, so I couldn't possibly help with /that/).

Answer (score 6):

Move the `struct fraction` definition to "fraction.h" and

```
#include "fraction.h"
```

in both "fraction.c" and "matrix.c"

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to guess your intentions, but I'm guessing you need to pass a pointer to free_fraction.

```
free_fraction( &(freeMe->m[i][j]) );
```

Comment: ```freeMe->m[i][j]``` is already a pointer -- he calloc()'d *columns* number of ```fractionRef``` to ```matrix->m[i]```, and ```fractionRef``` is OP's pointer type.  I don't see any place where OP assigns a non-zero value to any of the element pointers, though that could be omitted by OP.  In fact, your code will cause erroneous calls to ```free```.  Only ```&(freeMe->m[i][0])``` was return from ```calloc```, and that was in the allocation of the *row*, because ```&(freeMe->m[i][0]) == freeMe->m[i]```.  This answer introduces a dangerous bug.

Answer (score 2):

While in there, you may also want to change your definitions.

Better way so you understand what's going on:

```
struct fraction {
   int integer;
   int num;
   int den;
};
typedef struct fraction fractionType; // We can now use fractionType and it'll be struct fraction

typedef fractionType * fractionTypePtr; // We can now use fractionTypePtr and it will be a pointer to a fractionType which is a struct fraction
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you do want to totally hide the implementation of your fraction structure, you can have, in fraction.h:

```
typedef struct fraction* fractionRef;
```

and the actual declaration of your struct fraction in the fraction.c file.

However as you do hide the implementation, you must also define function for all the actions you can issue on a fraction, like, getting the value of numerator and denominator, i.e. writing things like:

```
get_numerator(f);
```

instead of:

```
f->num;
```

Comment: If you follow this advice, which I wouldn't, you will also have to create a function in fraction.c which allocates struct fraction -- because sizeof(struct fraction) could not be known outside of fraction.c.

Comment: Ahh yes thanks, I do have the fraction methods all set out such as: int getNumerator(fractionRef); void setNumerator (fractionRef, int); fractionRef add (fractionRef, fractionRef); void printFr (fractionRef, int); .. etc. Thanks

Comment: Or, you treat it the object oriented way, hide totally your struct implementation, and have a struct holding only pointers to the functions that can act on your fraction, as well as an opaque pointer to the fraction itself.