# Invalid use of undefined struct workqueue_struct

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I create a `workqueue` with `create_workqueue`, and then I want to print the name of the `workqueue`. The name should be the same name that I've used in `create_workqueue` as an argument. However, when I try to use `my_workqueue->name` it says that this is an invalid use of the struct. The item [`name`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/workqueue.c#L267) exists in the structure.

```c
static int __init my_init(void)
{
    struct workqueue_struct *my_workqueue = create_workqueue("myworkqueue");
    pr_info("%s\n", my_workqueue->name);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aside: please see [What does double underscore ( __const) mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449181/what-does-double-underscore-const-mean-in-c) *In C, symbols starting with an underscore followed by either an upper-case letter or another underscore are reserved for the implementation.*

Comment: `struct workqueue_struct` is not completely defined by `#include <linux/workqueue.h>`. `struct workqueue_struct *` should be treated as an opaque pointer type.

Comment: @WeatherVane This is proper usage of `__init` in Linux kernel code. (It expands to some GCC section attribute, allowing the code section to be discarded later.)

Comment: @Ian Abbott oh ok, thanks. I missed the space.

Comment: @IanAbbott Can you elobrate please? Also, can you please explain what is the difference between `work_struct` and `workqueue_struct`? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C: "invalid use of undefined type ‘struct X’ & dereferencing pointer to incomplete type" errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943251/c-invalid-use-of-undefined-type-struct-x-dereferencing-pointer-to-incomple). In short: You cannot access fields of the struct `workqueue_struct` which is **defined** in (other) **source** file `kernel/workqueue.c`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks. But when I use and access data from [`struct work_struct workq;`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/workqueue.h#L102), everything works fine, seems like it is defined in `linux/workqueue.h`.

Comment: Yes, the struct `work_struct` is **defined** in the **header** file `linux/workqueue.h`. That is why you can access its fields. That is the core of the difference: you can `#include` a **header** file into your code and get all definitions from it. But you cannot (shouldn't) `#include` a **source** file, so its definitions are not accessible.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Ohh I get you. Yeah I didn't realize it is a source and not a header file.